# How to check the input checkbox field with a value on page load using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( window ).load(function() {
            $( "#check" ).val('hurray_checked');
        });
    });
</script>       


<input id="check" type="checkbox" name="should_be_checked_when_pageloads" value="" />
```

So what all i want is when the page loads, the below field should become

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" name="should_be_checked_when_pageloads" value="hurray_checked" />
```

But my above code is not working, can anyone please let me know how to check a field with a value when page loads ?

Comment: Any reason why you've used both `.ready` & `.load`?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to set the value of the checkbox, check the checkbox or do both?

Comment: Actually i want to put the value to the field when the page loads thats all, sorry i am new to javascript..

Comment: I _think_ he wants to check the checkbox if the value is `hurray_checked`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use load

[load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/Window.onload) is called when all assets are done loading, including images. ready is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".check" ).attr("checked","checked").val('hurray_checked');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery's .prop

```
$(function(){
  $('.check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try below..for class u have to take "." and for id u should take"#"

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

            $( window ).load(function() {
                $( ".check" ).val('**hurray_checked**');
                    });

            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not put you code in `$( window ).load`,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $( "#check" ).val('hurray_checked');

    });
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

Either you use this:

```
   $( window ).load(function() {
        $( ".check" ).val('**hurray_checked**');//the selector you are should be class
   });
```

This will add the value whent the window is loaded

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".check" ).val('**hurray_checked**');
   });
```

This will add the value when the document is ready(loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` inplace of `#` like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".check" ).val('hurray_checked');
// ----^-- . in place of # as you used class in checkbox
   $( ".check" ).prop('checked',true);// to check the checkbox
});
```

Read **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop)**

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/wGhXk/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        $('#check').prop('checked', true);    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMVdc/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load` event is called before `$(document).ready`, and you are defining it after it has happened. That means your code never gets called.

You must either remove `$(window).load` wrapper, or `$(document).ready` for it to work as you expect.